# Reset the animation of user control when mouse leave

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I want to display a user control on a rectangle with some animation when mouse move over the rectangle, reset the animation and collapse the user control when mouse leave.

My question is how should I "reset" the animation as my current approached is just collapses the user control when mouse leave. Below is my demo code.

EDITTED:

ControlLibrary.xaml

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style>
      <Style.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="opacityStoryBoard">
                    <Storyboard  >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:10" From="0" To="2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.MouseLeave">
                <SeekStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="opacityStoryBoard" Offset="00:00:00">  </SeekStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Opacity" Value="0"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Content="Welcome" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
    Foreground="White"  Background="Transparent" FontSize="25" Height="300" Margin="10,0" />

    <!--<Image Height="300" x:Name="qr" Margin="10,0"  />-->


 </StackPanel>
```

---

mainWindow.xaml

```
<myToolTip:UserControl1 Visibility="Collapsed" 
        x:Name="customToolTip" />

    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="322" Stroke="Black" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="518" MouseMove="Rectangle_MouseMove_1"   MouseLeave="Rectangle_MouseLeave_1">
    </Rectangle>
```

---

mainWindow.cs

```
      private void Rectangle_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        customToolTip.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    }

    private void Rectangle_MouseLeave_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        customToolTip.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Please guide me..Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SeekStoryBoard` class to reset the animation time when the mouse leaves the rectangle.

For example:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Name="opacityStoryBoard">
                    <Storyboard  >
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="00:00:10" From="0" To="2" />
                    </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Opacity" Value="0"/>
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <SeekStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="opacityStoryBoard" Offset="00:00:00"></SeekStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I can't make it works.Should I modify anything at the code behind?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?? Did you overwrite the triggers in the Usercontrol's style with these? And did you notice I gave the storyboard a name?

Comment: yes..i overwritten and add in the name already but the animation won't reset when mouse leave.

Comment: You didn't add your entire MainWindow.xaml but I think I know what's wrong - updated my answer

Comment: Wow! It works like a charm. Thank you very much!..Wpf is really confusing, I need a proper study on these. Which website or tutorials do you recommend to read? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I recommend getting a good book on the subject... [WPF 4 Unleashed](http://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672331195) for instance

Comment: Okay, I will go get some from library and have a look. Thanks alot!